# great ancestor & great great ancestor

Tags: xpath

1/ I have rule checker that forbid elements depending on a xpath expression.

2/ Every "test" element can contain a "test" element recursivly

3/ I want to forbid the "non usage" of an attibute for the firsts 3 "test" elements

Exemple:

```
<test targetAttribute="level 1">
   <test targetAttribute="level 2">
      <test targetAttribute="level 3">
         <test targetAttribute="level 4">
            <test targetAttribute="level 5">
            </test>
         </test>
      </test>
   </test>
</test>
```

targetAttribute attribute is mandatory for the firsts 3 levels only all other descendant element from level3 have their targetAttribute optionnal.

Here are my xpath:

```
//test[not(targetAttribute)]/ancestor[1]::test (level1)
//test[not(targetAttribute)]/ancestor[2]::test (level2)
//test[not(targetAttribute)]/ancestor[3]::test (level3)
```

But it doesn't work ! I also tried without success:

```
//test/ancestor[1]::test[not(targetAttribute)]
```

I'm becoming crazy @_@ can someone help me plz ?

Comment: Thx @Kudin ! Actually the answer to my problem is: //test[not(@targetAttribute)][not(ancestor::test[3])]. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to select an attribute you need to use `@` before the attribute name. So

`//test[not(targetAttribute)]`

should be changed to

`//test[not(@targetAttribute)]`

and it will get all the `test` elements that do not contain this `@targetAttribute`.

Second thing.
When you want to select the first closest ancestor `test` you should use index after the test, like so:

```
/ancestor::test[1]
```

this will select the closes ancestor that is test (immediate parent in this case).

```
/ancestor::test[2]
```

will give you the grandparent and `3` will produce grand-grand parent.

Also you should probably filter out ancestors that don't have `@targetAttribute`

Not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish, but just a try:

`//test[not(@targetAttribute)]/ancestor::test[@targetAttribute][3]` (level1)

`//test[not(@targetAttribute)]/ancestor::test[@targetAttribute][2]` (level2)

`//test[not(@targetAttribute)]/ancestor::test[@targetAttribute][1]` (level3)